# AlarmManager on Android won't fire anything

Tags: android, android-alarms

I'm trying to make Android fire a Alarm at a certain time the user specifies to check if the user has posted to the service. However, Android won't fire the intent.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
 android:name="me.kennydude.dailybooth.NoBoothNotify.AlarmReciever" />
<service
 android:name="me.kennydude.dailybooth.NoBoothNotify.AlarmService">
</service>
```

NoBoothNotify.java function that sets the alarm:

```
public static void settingsChanged(){
    Context cntxt = DailyboothApplication.getInstance();
    String value = DailyboothShared.getPersonalSetting("noBoothNotify", "no");
    AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) cntxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent piI = new Intent(cntxt, AlarmReciever.class);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5){
        SharedPreferences prefs = DailyboothShared.getPrefs();
        piI.putExtra("account", prefs.getString("current_account", null));
    }
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cntxt, 348347873, piI, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if(value.equals("no")){
        alm.cancel(pi);
    } else{
        String[] values = value.split(":");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("s", value);
        // cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Log.d("s", "setting for " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
        Log.d("s", "HRD: " + cal.getTime().toGMTString());
        alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                /*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,*/ pi);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to just get it working one (hence the commented out part), however it doesn't work still.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but you do realise that when you set an alarm, it is expecting a time in UTC. If your timezone isn't UTC (GMT) you'll need to compensate.

Comment: Okay, so I've changed the code and it is now throwing out a time in UTC/GMT. However, it still doesn't fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this. For some reason Android doesn't like to fire Alarms if the receiver is a subclass.

To fix and keep origination, I moved it all to a new namespace and it worked.

Joe