# Setting up AlarmManager to run when Android app isn't running?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I've looked at several guides and I've basically done this:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity 
{
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));

      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

      Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Receiver.class);
      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, myIntent,0);

      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**Receiver.java**

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` also contains `<receiver android:name=".Receiver"/>`.

So, from what I've read, the above code should show a `toast` whenever it is 10 pm in New York, whether or not the app is actually running. At present, it does nothing, even if the app is running. It looks like the `Receiver` class isn't even being called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem (as was hinted to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004237/alarmmanager-on-android-wont-fire-anything)): my `Main.java` and `Receiver.java` files were not placed in the same package. I don't understand the logic behind this. I like separating my `java` files into different packages for organization purposes, but apparently Android doesn't like this.

If anyone can tell me how to do the above with the `java` files in 2 different packages/folders under `src`, I'll make that the correct answer.

Comment: your answer is the right answer, and now you are asking another one. IMHO you should post another question, but not here. 1Q=1A

Answer (score 0):

do you register you Receiver with intent-filter?
like below

```
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. Please provide an example.

Comment: I'm sorry again. Could you explain where within the manifest I should place this `intent-filter`? What is `android:priority` and why did you set it to that number? And is `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` exactly what I should copy or should it be something else in my case?